# Why would a .ins file create null output files/

Tags: installing, dtx

I had a .dtx/.ins pair of files using dox.sty which installed a .sty file and half a dozen ancillary files, which has been working perfectly for years.

After a long series of edits, it now only creates null files: that is, it creates only empty files (size 0) for the .sty file and all the others.

Clearly  I edited something that caused this, but before I start the long task of unwinding from the versioned repository and chopping down the code, I thought I'd ask if anyone has come across this before.

I know that an unguarded line in a .dtx file (one not starting with percent space) can get output verbatim as part of a generated file as if it were part of the macrocode content, but in this case there are none.

Comment: tex will make a zero sized file if you `\immediate\openout` some stream then `\immediate\closeout` it without writing anything. so most likely your .ins file is causing the files to be opened but the content isn't being pulled from the dtx because er well because of something you did wrong:-) hard to guess.

Comment: Yep. More likely I have goofed in the .dtx  file though: the .ins  file hasn't changed in months.